# Know the owner of a patent when initial filing company no longer exists

Tags: owner, merger

When a patent was filed by a **company that no longer exists**, what is the best way to find out its current owner?

In my case the company that filed the patent at the time first merged with a second company. The resulting company then sold some of its assets (most of them corresponding to the initial company) to multiple other companies. So it's very hard to guess who owns the specific patent.

*When looking at the patent history I can't find any information on any owner change, and I'm not actually sure this information is available anyway.*

Answer (score 1):

You can access recorded assignments via [this link](https://assignment.uspto.gov/patent/index.html#/patent/search). If no assignment is recorded, and you still want to find the owner, you can reach out to the attorney of record.

Comment: Assignments are not required and the attorney of record in the USPTO data is going to be the person who filed and prosecuted the application. It is somewhere to start but, especially after a merger, that person is very unlikely to still be involved with the patent.